# Video stabilisation software

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

Is there any way, either through a graphical program or a command line utility to "stabilise" video in Ubuntu?

By stabilise I am referring mainly to a feature of iMovie where shaky video is analysed, and then frame by frame altered to make it look smoother. This method looses video quality through zooming and rotating to produce the effect. Look [[image] at this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jwZFLTMF60) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: I don't know much about video, but the shakiness in your example doesn't look like the kind of shakiness those apps are designed to eliminate. Perhaps try mounting it on the frame, rather than your helmet?

Comment: couldn't you do it in ubuntu?

Answer (score 15):

The `transcode` package bundles an image stabiliser plugin [vid.stab](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/features.php?lang=en). Their video demo certainly looks convincing (if a little vomit inducing).

[Transcode package](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/transcode) is no longer maintained and was removed from Ubuntu releases 18.04 and newer. You may [still be able to run it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transcode) but functions may be limited or buggy.

Comment: It is now available as a filter in ffmpeg 2.0, though ffmpeg itself is not available for Ubuntu :(

Comment: @FairMiles ffmpeg is available in the Ubuntu repositories, but not vidstab apparently.

Answer (score 9):

You can try Cinelerra,

### **Installing cinelerra**

- Add the following PPA `ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa` ([How to add a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) then install cinelerra from the software center.

### Tutorials

- Have a look at **[this](http://crazedmuleproductions.blogspot.com/2009/03/motion-stabilization-tutorial.html)**.

Comment: Looking at that tutorial is quite disappointing - compared to what I'm used to in iMovie then the process is lengthy, and the result does not seem as good either.

Answer (score 8):

FFmpeg [deshake filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake).

```
ffmpeg -i "$INPUT" -vf deshake=rx=64:ry=64:blocksize=32 -strict -2 "$NEW_NAME"  ## :opencl=1
```

The higher the video resolution is, the more you need in `rx`, `ry` and `blocksize`. Check the link for documentation.

Here's a little script I use:

```
INPUT=$1
BASE_NAME=`basename "$INPUT"`
BASE_NAME="${BASE_NAME%.*}"
SUFFIX=${INPUT##*.}
NEW_NAME="$BASE_NAME"-deshake.$SUFFIX

set -x
ffmpeg -i "$INPUT" -vf deshake=rx=64:ry=64:blocksize=32 -strict -2 "$NEW_NAME"  ## :opencl=1
set +x
##  Copy the modification date too.
touch "$NEW_NAME" -r "$INPUT"
```

Although, I have to add, the results are not too good. I'd say it's better to upload to Youtube, let it deshake and download the result.

Comment: This made it worse for me.

Comment: unfortunately youtube removed the deshake feature from Youtube Studio

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) can be used now with [vid.stab](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab) to produce good quality stabilized videos.
There are a few sources ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409840/137608), [2](https://adrian.siemieniak.net/portal/how-to-stabilize-shaky-video-on-linux/), [3](https://rainnic.altervista.org/en/how-stabilize-video-using-ffmpeg-and-vidstab)) that report this.

If your video is named `input.mp4` execute

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=10:accuracy=15:result="mytransforms.trf" -f null -
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="mytransforms.trf" -c:a copy out_stabilized.mp4
```

The first step creates the stabilization profile.
The second step creates the stabilized video.
Other options for the second step are

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=input="mytransforms.trf",unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -c:a copy -preset fast out_stabilized.mp4
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="mytransforms.trf" -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out_stabilized.mp4
```

(the last is for high quality output).

More information on the parameters can be found in the vid.stab GitHub page.

**Related**:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515289/open-source-implementations-of-video-stabilization/10725141#10725141
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5638/video-editor-w-stabilization
3. https://dashcamtalk.com/forum/threads/how-to-stabilizing-your-video.19189/
4. [How to stabilize video with Kdenlive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926563/how-to-stabilize-video-with-kdenlive) (further details on how to use Kdenlive).

---

**Extra**

1. I have found [a plugin](https://imagej.net/plugins/image-stabilizer) for [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/), which is an outstanding image processing and analysis software used in many applications.

Comment: as above, this worked for me from link below

 I had to convert avi to mp4 first using ffmpeg -i  <input> <output>

https://rainnic.altervista.org/en/how-stabilize-video-using-ffmpeg-and-vidstab?language_content_entity=en

Comment: vid.stab developer says "Make sure that you use unsharp filter provided by ffmpeg for best results (only in second pass)." Maybe unsharp filter should already be in the first suggested 2nd command.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily stabilize videos with **Kdenlive**:

Right-click on a clip in the project library and select Clip Jobs -> Stabilize

[image]

Worked with Kdenlive 20.08.2 on Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 4):

You can try Shotcut (http://shotcut.org/). It's a NLE (Non linear editor) that comes with a lot of filters, including video stabilizing.
check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3v-jYJJfuM

Answer (score 3):

**Blender** is a free and open-source 3D creation suite. You can define tracking points to remove shakiness, bumps and jerks from video footage using the **2D video stabilization feature**.

To install **Blender** Run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blender
```

Alternatively, The latest version (3.0.1) can be [Downloaded from the Blender Website.](https://www.blender.org/download/)

Video stabilization instructions are documented in [the Blender 3.0 Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/movie_clip/tracking/clip/sidebar/stabilization/introduction.html)

**Here is a basic overview to use the Stabilization Feature:**

1. Tap on "open" to load the video clip.
2. Click on the "set scene frame" located on the left to generate the video timeline.
3. Click on "Tracking settings" and select locRot. Add as many markers as you want for location and rotation.
4. Now click on the "Stabilization" tab to enable 2D stabilization.

   [image]
5. Select the tracks for location and rotation you marked earlier.
6. Tap on "clip display" located at the top and select "show stable".

   [image]
7. Now click on "Autoscale". Or if you prefer to adjust according to your preference then you can move the slider to get the desired results.
8. Play the video and enjoy the stable version of your footage.
9. Tap on "save" to save the video clip.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MLT](https://www.mltframework.org), which is versatile and well maintained.
A command line tool for this is `melt`.
There are [detailed instructions](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/329-ubuntu-trusty-rotate-stabilize-video-melt-vidstab), and [a script](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/tree/master/video) for that. It is 3 years old, but I think is is still functional.

**Related**:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255944/understanding-controlling-mlt-melt-slideshow
2. https://www.mankier.com/1/mlt-melt
3. https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterVidstab/ , https://mltframework.org/plugins/FilterVideostab2/ , https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterAvfilter-deshake/ , https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterDeshake/ ,

Answer (score 0):

vidstab1.1 will work but is not simple to implement [vidstab1.1 website](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/) and it's componenets are available via synaptic.