# Removing/reducing camera shakyness?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video stabilisation software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19095/video-stabilisation-software)

I strapped a video camera to my motorbike helmet and took this video: http://www.flickr.com/photos/rorymccann/4787401579/

Since it's strapped to my head and I'm on a motorcycle on country roads, it bounces up and down a bit. Is there any application that will automatically 'remove' this bouncyness?

I'm thinking of an application that would offset each frame of the image and add black borders, so that the 'centre' of the video would be tried to be kept in the centre as much as possible.

I know it's not possible to remove *all* shakyness, and the video might look odd with all the black borders, but I'd like to check I'm not reinventing the wheel before I write this myself. Some google searching throws up some applications, are there any for ubuntu linux?